# Can't install NVIDIA drivers (Unable to load 'nvidia.ko')

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

To be simple, I have an error when trying to install nvidia drivers for my Geforce GTX 1050 on my laptop (Fedora 31).

First of all here are some infos:

```
[Chetrit@localhost nvidia_installers]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 1 20:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
[Chetrit@localhost nvidia_installers]$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

And the adequated official driver I installed : `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run` .

When launching it (from tty mode), and after tryed everything to blacklist / clear remove "Nouveau" driver, this is the error I get that I can't get rid of:

> ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA GPU(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.

Here is the full log:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu Jul 16 09:22:46 2020
installer version: 450.57

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> Tagging shared libraries with chcon -t textrel_shlib_t.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 450.57.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="/usr/bin/cc".
-> Performing CC check.
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/source'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/build'
-> Performing Compiler check.
-> Performing Dom0 check.
-> Performing Xen check.
-> Performing PREEMPT_RT check.
-> Performing vgpu_kvm check.
-> Cleaning kernel module build directory.
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; /usr/bin/make -k -j8 clean NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/source" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/build"'...
   rm -f -r conftest
   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64'
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64'
-> Building kernel modules
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; /usr/bin/make -k -j8  NV_EXCLUDE_KERNEL_MODULES="" SYSSRC="/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/source" SYSOUT="/lib/modules/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64/build"'...
   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64'
     SYMLINK /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
     SYMLINK /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o
    CONFTEST: hash__remap_4k_pfn
    CONFTEST: set_pages_uc
    CONFTEST: list_is_first
    CONFTEST: set_memory_uc
    CONFTEST: set_memory_array_uc
    CONFTEST: set_pages_array_uc
    CONFTEST: acquire_console_sem
    CONFTEST: console_lock
    CONFTEST: ioremap_cache
    CONFTEST: ioremap_wc
    CONFTEST: acpi_walk_namespace
    CONFTEST: sg_alloc_table
    CONFTEST: pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot
    CONFTEST: get_num_physpages
    CONFTEST: efi_enabled
    CONFTEST: pde_data
    CONFTEST: proc_remove
    CONFTEST: pm_vt_switch_required
    CONFTEST: xen_ioemu_inject_msi
    CONFTEST: phys_to_dma
    CONFTEST: get_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: write_cr4
    CONFTEST: of_get_property
    CONFTEST: of_find_node_by_phandle
    CONFTEST: of_node_to_nid
    CONFTEST: pnv_pci_get_npu_dev
    CONFTEST: of_get_ibm_chip_id
    CONFTEST: node_end_pfn
    CONFTEST: pci_bus_address
    CONFTEST: pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device
    CONFTEST: pci_remove_bus_device
    CONFTEST: register_cpu_notifier
    CONFTEST: cpuhp_setup_state
    CONFTEST: dma_map_resource
    CONFTEST: backlight_device_register
    CONFTEST: timer_setup
    CONFTEST: pci_enable_msix_range
    CONFTEST: do_gettimeofday
    CONFTEST: kernel_read
    CONFTEST: kernel_write
    CONFTEST: kthread_create_on_node
    CONFTEST: of_find_matching_node
    CONFTEST: dev_is_pci
    CONFTEST: dma_direct_map_resource
    CONFTEST: tegra_get_platform
    CONFTEST: flush_cache_all
    CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn
    CONFTEST: jiffies_to_timespec
    CONFTEST: ktime_get_raw_ts64
    CONFTEST: ktime_get_real_ts64
    CONFTEST: address_space_init_once
    CONFTEST: kbasename
    CONFTEST: vzalloc
    CONFTEST: wait_on_bit_lock_argument_count
    CONFTEST: bitmap_clear
    CONFTEST: usleep_range
    CONFTEST: radix_tree_empty
    CONFTEST: radix_tree_replace_slot
    CONFTEST: pnv_npu2_init_context
    CONFTEST: cpumask_of_node
    CONFTEST: drm_dev_unref
    CONFTEST: drm_reinit_primary_mode_group
    CONFTEST: get_user_pages_remote
    CONFTEST: get_user_pages
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_lookup
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_state_ref_counting
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_res_obj
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_funcs_have_mode_in_name
    CONFTEST: drm_framebuffer_get
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_get
    CONFTEST: drm_dev_put
    CONFTEST: drm_format_num_planes
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_for_each_possible_encoder
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_of_node_to_nid
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_map_sg_attrs
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present___close_fd
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd_flags
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_screen_info
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_kthread_create_on_node
    CONFTEST: acpi_op_remove
    CONFTEST: outer_flush_all
    CONFTEST: file_operations
    CONFTEST: file_inode
    CONFTEST: kuid_t
    CONFTEST: dma_ops
    CONFTEST: swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: noncoherent_swiotlb_dma_ops
    CONFTEST: vm_fault_has_address
    CONFTEST: backlight_properties_type
    CONFTEST: vm_insert_pfn_prot
    CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn_prot
    CONFTEST: vm_ops_fault_removed_vma_arg
    CONFTEST: vmbus_channel_has_ringbuffer_page
    CONFTEST: device_driver_of_match_table
    CONFTEST: device_of_node
    CONFTEST: node_states_n_memory
    CONFTEST: kmem_cache_has_kobj_remove_work
    CONFTEST: sysfs_slab_unlink
    CONFTEST: proc_ops
    CONFTEST: vmalloc_has_pgprot_t_arg
    CONFTEST: timeval
    CONFTEST: mm_has_mmap_lock
    CONFTEST: address_space
    CONFTEST: backing_dev_info
    CONFTEST: mm_context_t
    CONFTEST: vm_fault_t
    CONFTEST: mmu_notifier_ops_invalidate_range
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_present
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_bus_type
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_irq
    CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_name
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_legacy_dev_list
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_set_busid
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_connectors_changed
    CONFTEST: drm_init_function_args
    CONFTEST: drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct
    CONFTEST: drm_master_drop_has_from_release_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_unload_has_int_return_type
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_crtc_destroy_state_has_crtc_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_crtc_helper_funcs_has_atomic_enable
    CONFTEST: drm_mode_object_find_has_file_priv_arg
    CONFTEST: dma_buf_owner
    CONFTEST: drm_connector_list_iter
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_swap_state_has_stall_arg
    CONFTEST: drm_driver_prime_flag_present
    CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_has_resv
    CONFTEST: dom0_kernel_present
    CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_hyperv_available
    CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_kvm_build
    CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_build
    CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_csp_build
    CONFTEST: pm_runtime_available
    CONFTEST: drm_available
    CONFTEST: drm_atomic_available
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_inc
    CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_dec_and_test
    CONFTEST: drm_alpha_blending_available
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-frontend.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-cray.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-dma.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-i2c.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.o
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c: In function 'nvidia_mmap':
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:662:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
     662 |     int i = 0;
         |         ^
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c: In function 'nv_encode_caching':
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:334:16: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
     334 |             if (NV_ALLOW_CACHING(memory_type))
         |                ^
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.c:336:9: note: here
     336 |         default:
         |         ^~~~~~~
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-p2p.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pat.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-usermap.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-vm.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-vtophys.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-interface.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-mlock.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-pci.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-registry.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-usermap.o
   /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.o: warning: objtool: .text.unlikely: unexpected end of section
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci-table.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-memdbg.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-ibmnpu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-report-err.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-rsync.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-msi.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-caps.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_linux.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_caps.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/linux_nvswitch.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/procfs_nvswitch.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ampere.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ampere_ce.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ampere_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ampere_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm_utils.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm_common.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm_linux.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/nvstatus.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/nvCpuUuid.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/nv-kthread-q.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/nv-kthread-q-selftest.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tools.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_global.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_isr.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_procfs.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_space.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_space_mm.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_semaphore.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mem.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_rm_mem.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_channel.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_lock.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_hal.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_tree.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_allocator.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_range.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_group.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_replayable_faults.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_non_replayable_faults.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_access_counters.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_events.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_module.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pte_batch.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tlb_batch.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_push.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pushbuffer.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_thread_context.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tracker.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_ce.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_maxwell.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_maxwell_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_ce.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_fault_buffer.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_volta_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_volta_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_volta.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_volta_fault_buffer.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_volta_access_counter_buffer.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_turing.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_turing_mmu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_turing_host.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_policy.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_utils.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kvmalloc.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_sysmem.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_gpu.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_migrate.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_populate_pageable.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_migrate_pageable.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_map_external.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_user_channel.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_hmm.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_heuristics.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_thrashing.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_prefetch.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ats_ibm.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ats_faults.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_test_rng.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_tree_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_allocator_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_semaphore_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mem_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_rm_mem_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_page_tree_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tracker_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_push_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_channel_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ce_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_lock_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_utils_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kvmalloc_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_sysmem_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_events_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_module_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_get_rm_ptes_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_fault_buffer_flush_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mmu_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_peer_identity_mappings_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_group_tree_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_thread_context_test.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nvidia-modeset-linux.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nv-kthread-q.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-drv.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-utils.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-crtc.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-encoder.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-connector.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fb.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-modeset.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-prime-fence.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-linux.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-helper.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nv-pci-table.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-nvkms-memory.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem-user-memory.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-format.o
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia.o
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset.o
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm.o
   ld -r -o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-interface.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-frontend.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-acpi.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-cray.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-dma.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-i2c.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-mmap.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-p2p.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pat.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-procfs.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia
   /nv-usermap.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-vm.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-vtophys.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-interface.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-mlock.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-pci.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-registry.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/os-usermap.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-pci-table.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-memdbg.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-ibmnpu.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-report-err.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-rsync.o /tmp/selfgz
   14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-msi.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv-caps.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_linux.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_caps.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/linux_nvswitch.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia/procfs_nvswitch.o
   ld -r -o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-interface.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nvidia-modeset-linux.o /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset/nv-kthread-q.o
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm.o
     MODPOST 4 modules
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm.mod.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset.mod.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm.mod.o
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia.mod.o
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-drm.ko
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-modeset.ko
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia-uvm.ko
     LD [M]  /tmp/selfgz14023/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57/kernel/nvidia.ko
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.7.7-100.fc31.x86_64'
-> done.
-> Kernel module compilation complete.
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA GPU(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.

Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for more information.
-> Kernel module load error: Cannot allocate memory
-> Kernel messages:
[ 1660.744089]  nv_register_procfs+0x4c/0x250 [nvidia]
[ 1660.744165]  nvidia_init_module+0x18/0x597 [nvidia]
[ 1660.744166]  ? 0xffffffffc10a7000
[ 1660.744240]  nvidia_frontend_init_module+0x4f/0x93 [nvidia]
[ 1660.744243]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x200
[ 1660.744245]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
[ 1660.744247]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x16b/0x220
[ 1660.744248]  ? do_init_module+0x23/0x230
[ 1660.744249]  do_init_module+0x5c/0x230
[ 1660.744251]  load_module+0x28a6/0x2b00
[ 1660.744253]  ? __do_sys_init_module+0x146/0x170
[ 1660.744254]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
[ 1660.744255]  __do_sys_init_module+0x146/0x170
[ 1660.744256]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x1c0
[ 1660.744258]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[ 1660.744259] RIP: 0033:0x7f77831251bd
[ 1660.744260] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 9b 5c 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[ 1660.744261] RSP: 002b:00007ffe16072b98 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000af
[ 1660.744262] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 00007f77831251bd
[ 1660.744262] RDX: 0000000000425c48 RSI: 00000000024e8ca0 RDI: 00007f77808da000
[ 1660.744262] RBP: 00007ffe16072d40 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1660.744263] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000002
[ 1660.744263] R13: 0000000000425c48 R14: 00007f77808da000 R15: 00000000019db210
[ 1660.744265] ---[ end trace 9d9c2fa4492b9112 ]---
[ 1660.744266] NVRM: failed to register procfs.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I tried a lot of different things in order to get rid of this error, watching solutions for people that had the same problems, nothing really did work, hope you'll find some solutions, thanks.

Comment: Please try asking at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148 - there are very knowledgeable people over there

Comment: There is a good article in fedora magazine on how to install nvidia drivers without directly using nvidia's binary driver file: https://fedoramagazine.org/install-nvidia-gpu/. I suggest you try this.

Comment: Regarding your present problem, even if one disables nouveau driver, it is best to run the nvidia installer in TUI mode. This can be done by typing `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and restarting the system. GUI mode can be re-enabled (once installation is successful) by typing `systemctl set-default graphical.target` and then restarting the system.